# is there a library to fetch user avatars?

Tags: user-interface, avatars

Let's suppose we are adding users to a platform using the email address.

Until the invited users don't upload an avatar or a profile picture, the best we can display is either a generic "user icon" or a identicon (or similar).

I assume that given the email address, there's a possibility that the user is on LinkedIN, Google plus, facebook, twitter and who knows where.

Is there a library or do you have experience in writing an algorithm that will try to fetch a profile picture from multiple channels?

--edit--

I am aware of automatically generated avatars (identicon), but what I am really trying to achieve is personal avatar that belongs to the user.

Comment: Can you use Gravatar to get the profile picture with the email address? It's an incredibly popular platform and I've used it successfully myself. Also, there are libraries available!

Comment: gravatar.com only displays automatically generated avatars for users that haven't uploaded their own yet. Try plugging in the MD5 hash of my email address: ac01d8d04fdbc53742f47257473a8a1e

Comment: But it means that you uploaded your avatar on Gravatar? My typical user will definitely not upload an avatar on Gravatar

Answer (score 1):

The [gravatar API](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/) is the simplest option:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef?s=80&d=identicon&r=g
```

Result:

[image]

The long hex number is the md5 hash of the user's email address (trimmed and lowercase). `s` is the avatar size.